# Displaying next object in array onclick

Tags: angularjs

I can't get the next index in the array to appear on the screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Currently if I hit the left arrow I get the Trek bike and if I hit the right arrow I get the Mongoose, but no more bikes appear onclick with either button. Any help is appreciated.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('BikeController',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.bikeSlide = false;


$scope.products = [
{
manufacturer: "Trek",
image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
}, 
{
manufacturer: "Mongoose",
image: 'images/bike2.jpg'

},
{   

    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Giant",
image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
},
{

    manufacturer: "Framed",
image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
},
{
manufacturer: "Windsor",
image: 'images/bike6.jpg'
}
];


$scope.LeftArrowClick =function(selectedIndex){
$scope.selectedIndex--;
    $scope.selectedObject = $scope.products[selectedIndex];

if ($scope == -1){
$scope = 6;

}
};

$scope.RightArrowClick =function(selectedIndex){
$scope.selectedIndex++;
    $scope.selectedObject = $scope.products[selectedIndex];

if ($scope == 7){
$scope = 0;

}
};


}]);
```

index.html

```
 <div class="products" ng-controller="BikeController">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-1" id="leftArrow" ng-click="LeftArrowClick(0)">
            <a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/leftarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="bikesandtitles">

            <div id="bikeTitle" class="col-md-8 text-center">
                {{selectedObject.manufacturer}} {{selectedObject.images[0]}}
                <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{selectedObject.image}}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1" id="rightArrow" ng-click="RightArrowClick(1)">
            <a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/rightarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
<!--End controller-->
```

Comment: What it means? `if ($scope == -1){ $scope = 6;` `if ($scope == 7){ $scope = 0;`

Comment: He/she's wrapping around both directions when the index goes 'too far'.

Comment: Try debugging by logging to console the selected index?

Comment: There are 6 products total so if it hits 7 then it resets back to 0

Comment: You're comparing the **whole** `$scope`  with a number, are you sure about this?

Comment: I wouldn't say I'm positive,but if I assign it like  if\($scope = 7){$scope = 0;} then onclick I get this error.3angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.LeftArrowClick (app.js:40)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14605), <anonymous>:4:241)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15694)
    at callback (angular.js:25622)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17544)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous
    at defaultHandlerWrapper 
    at HTMLDivElement.eventHandler

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes on your code. Try this:

HTML:

```
  <div class="col-md-1" id="leftArrow" ng-click="displayProduct(-1)">
    <a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/leftarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="bikesandtitles">

    <div id="bikeTitle" class="col-md-8 text-center">
      {{selectedObject.manufacturer}} {{selectedObject.image}}
      <img id="bikePic" ng-src="{{selectedObject.image}}">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1" id="rightArrow" ng-click="displayProduct(1)">
    <a ng-href="#"><img ng-src="images/rightarrow.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('BikeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.bikeSlide = false;

  $scope.products = [{
    manufacturer: "Trek",
    image: 'images/bike1.jpg'
  }, {
    manufacturer: "Mongoose",
    image: 'images/bike2.jpg'
  }, {
    manufacturer: "Portlandia",
    image: 'images/bike3.jpg'
  }, {
    manufacturer: "Giant",
    image: 'images/bike4.jpg'
  }, {
    manufacturer: "Framed",
    image: 'images/bike5.jpg'
  }, {
    manufacturer: "Windsor",
    image: 'images/bike6.jpg'
  }];

  $scope.displayProduct = function(increment) {
    var actualIndex = $scope.products.indexOf($scope.selectedObject) || 0;
    var index = actualIndex + increment;
    if (index < 0)
      index = $scope.products.length - 1;
    if (index >= $scope.products.length)
      index = 0;
    $scope.selectedObject = $scope.products[index];
  };

}]);
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/w2CtaFbl5l4d1BY663So

Comment: Why the negative vote? Could you at least tell me what happened?